# creating an uneditable jtable displayed in jframe

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe

i have come across jtables today, as a nice way of representing information retrieved from a database, for example, like in the following code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class JTableCreatingDemo {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Object rowData[][] = { { "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "Row1-Column3" },
        { "Row2-Column1", "Row2-Column2", "Row2-Column3" } };
    Object columnNames[] = { "Column One", "Column Two", "Column Three" };
    JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(300, 150);
    frame.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

the only thing i don't like about it is that if i click on the table entries, i can change them. i don't like this. i was wondering if there is a way that i can prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `AbstractTableModel`, but that might be more work than you're prepared for, instead, use a `DefaultTableModel` and override it's `isCellEditable` method to return `false`

For example...

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames) {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }
};
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details